# Extend custom System.Web.UI.Page implementer to include custom property than can be accessed by page and master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a class called BasePage which inherits System.Web.UI.Page. On this page I've declared a property called UserSession which I want to be able to access from any Page/MasterPage.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string UserSession { get; set; }

    public BasePage()
    {
        base.PreInit += new EventHandler(BasePage_PreInit);
    }

    private void BasePage_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserSession = "12345";
    }
}
```

My Default.aspx.cs page inherits the BasePage class and allows me to access the UserSession property as expected.

```
public partial class Default : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(UserSession);
    }
}
```

However, even though Default.aspx has MasterPage.Master assigned correctly, when I try and access the UserSession property from MasterPage.Master.cs it can't find it and won't build.

So what am I trying to achieve by doing this? I want to expose a UserSession object to every page in my application. Pretty simple you would have thought? Nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MasterPage` is separate in the heirarchy to `Page` so you cannot access the property directly from that. However, `MasterPage` does have a `Page` property that returns the `Page` object, which you can cast to your `BasePage` class. Then as long as `UserSession` is public (or internal, or protected internal, which might make good sense here) it can access that property. Unless you've only one master page codebehind, you may want to similarly create a BaseMasterPage and do something like:

```
public BaseMasterPage : MasterPage
{
  protected string UserSession
  {
    get
    {
      return (Page as BasePage).UserSession;
    }
    set
    {
      (Page as BasePage).UserSession = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of exposing an unlimited number of properties without having to declare each of them individually in the BaseMasterPage?

Comment: You could expose the `(Page as BasePage)` itself, and call it through `BasePage.UserSession` etc. though I'd argue against as exposing a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.  Declare your string variable as public.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: TheGeekYouNeed's answer is correct... I should know better than to try to answer questions this early on a Monday.

I think you'll need to create a base master page class which holds your UserSession property.  This would allow you to access the property from the masterpage as well as the pages that inherit from it.